# Get dates as check if it is ending

Tags: sql

im in a project and now im stuck on this. I need to read from a query to sql somedates and is id, and if that date if ending(lets say 20days range) , i will write something like "The item with id=? will end in 20days"

So far i got this

```
SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cmsPropertyData WHERE contentNodeId IN (SELECT contentNodeId FROm cmsPropertyData WHERE propertytypeid = 138 AND dataNtext LIKE '41')AND propertytypeid = 137 AND dataNtext IS NOT NULL AND dataNtext NOT LIKE ''";
myCommand.Connection = myCon;
myCon.Open();

SqlDataReader Reader;
Reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (Reader.Read())
{
    string getdatas = Reader["dataNtext"].ToString();
    Response.Write(getdatas);
}
```

But like this i get all the datas into one single string and i dont know even witch id she belongs to. Im problably doing the wrong way , so if someone can help i would appreciate :)

Comment: it would be great if you can at least describe your tables structures

Comment: It seems that C# code is not related to question. Could you just remove C# code and format SQL statement better?

Comment: @Pedro the only thing u need to work with is id and dataNtext , "id" is int and dataNText it is varchar , when i have more than one data on him i just need to split by "," . I just cant get a way of getting line by line and teste if the datas on it are close to end

Comment: @qxg is not related? i need to do this with c# i just use sql to get the dates and id's ..

Comment: First of all, create a MODEL. Deserialize the results to a collection of said modal. Then you can use C# to filter, manipulate, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Well your query is not clear. But if you want to find out if a row within 20 days range or not you do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM cmsPropertyData WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,dataNtext,GETDATE()) <= 20
```

Comment: Ure missing the point, i need to get the ones the ids where the dates are ending so i can send an e-mail "hey the item with id="??" is ending!" i can send the email i just need a way to check the ids where the dates are close to end

Comment: @user3584562 - Then you do this with `=` instead of `<=`.